# Koin: NoBeanDefFoundException, Check your module definitions

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

The koin test results as follows:

`org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for '<class_name>' has been found. Check your module definitions.`

the class `EmailValidatorUtilImpl` is well implemented,

```
import org.junit.After
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject

class EmailValidatorUtilImpl : EmailValidatorUtil {

    private val pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN)
    private var matcher: Matcher? = null

    override fun validateEmail(email: String): Boolean {
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email)
        return matcher!!.matches()
    }

    companion object {
        private val EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[a-zA-Z0-9#_~!$&'()*+,;=:.\"(),:;<>@\\[\\]\\\\]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$"
    }
}
```

and also, injected in KoinTest as below:

```
class EmailValidatorUtilImplTest : KoinTest, KoinComponent {

    private val validatorUtilImpl: EmailValidatorUtilImpl by inject()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        startKoin { module { single { EmailValidatorUtilImpl } } }
    }

    @Test
    fun `is valid email returns true`() {
        val isEmailValid = validatorUtilImpl.validateEmail("someone@somewhere.com")
        Assert.assertTrue(isEmailValid)
    }

    @Test
    fun `is invalid email returns false`() {
        val isEmailValid = validatorUtilImpl.validateEmail("invalid_email")
        Assert.assertFalse(isEmailValid)
    }

    @After
    fun tearDown() {
        stopKoin()
    }
}
```

furthermore, the implementation class is been well injected as

```
var loginUtilsModule = module {
    single { EmailValidatorUtilImpl() }
}
```

in Application class:

```
startKoin {
            androidLogger(Level.DEBUG)
            androidContext(this@SampleApplication)
            modules(listOf(
                    loginUtilsModule
            ))
        }
```

dependencies (app/build.gradle):

```
    // di
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-androidx-scope:2.0.1'
    implementation 'org.koin:koin-android:2.0.1'

    // test
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.28.2'
    testImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // android test
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.koin:koin-test:2.0.1'
```

Comment: Have you tried taking out `KoinComponent` and just keeping `KoinTest` for the test?

Comment: Yes, tried. KoinComponent wasn't intentional.

Comment: Can you add your imports in the test file here and test dependencies in gradle?

Comment: @Napster updated in the question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the issue and the mistake was the module instead of **modules (or.koin.core.KoinApplication)**

```
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        startKoin { module { single { EmailValidatorUtilImpl } } }
    }
```

so, the solution and the correct version are:

```
    startKoin { modules(loginUtilsModule) }
```

Comment: saved my day, had the same issue with a ViewModel, thanks for finding this

Comment: after upgrade from v1 to v2, I spend a year to find a mistake from module to modules +.+

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem, but in my case Koin was unable to resolve an implementation of interface. I had:

```
interface MessagesRepository {...}

class MessagesRepositoryImpl : MessagesRepository {...}

class GetMessagesUseCase(private val messagesRepository: MessagesRepository) {...}
```

And in Koin module I wrote:

```
single { MessagesRepositoryImpl() }
single { GetMessagesUseCase(get()) }
```

So Koin couldn't find an instance of `MessagesRepository` to inject it into `GetMessagesUseCase`. Specifying singleton's type explicitly resolved the issue (but maybe there is a better solution):

```
single<MessagesRepository> { MessagesRepositoryImpl() }
single { GetMessagesUseCase(get()) }
```

Comment: This was my issue, except I had the dependency resolved in an other module. Weird

Comment: That was it for me too, thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
 single { MessagesRepositoryImpl() as MessagesRepository }
```

*Yamashiro Rion* you can do this

Comment: This is working for us, but having trouble understanding why casting unsafe resolved the issue.